# Printing binary heap in tree format, C language

Tags: c, printf, binary-tree

I made an array of integers (**mat** in the code) which has the Heap binary tree property so that the i-th node has **leftChild = i*2+1** and **rightChild = i*2+2**

If the i-th node is NULL then **mat[i] = -1**.
Here is a bit of the Print function i wrote:

```
int pos = 0, e = 0;
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) { // n = arr length

    if( mat[i] == -1 ) 
        printf(" ");
    else
        printf("%d  ", mat[i]);


    if( pos == 0 ) {
        pos = Power(2, e); // returns 2^e
        e++;
    }
    
    if( pos == 1 ) 
        printf("\n");

    pos--;
}
```

and this is what it prints if arr = {15, 5, 19, 1, 14, -1, 254, -1, 3, 13, -1, -1, -1, 240, 360}

```
15  
5  19  
1  14   254  
 3  13     240  360
```

I tried better formatting but I only got so far:

```
    15  
   5  19  
  1  14   254  
  3  13     240  360
```

I know a solution that would work is building a matrix but I figured there could be a different answer, do you have any tips?

Comment: `240, 360}` Why does the array end here? Shouldn't it be `240, 360, -1, -1`? Please show full code. First get to now your tree - find the depth of the tree and the longest length of the digits representing the numbers in the tree. Then you can calculate the number of spaces to be inserted, depending on the depth you are printing and the count of digits the number when printed will have. It's sadly a bit too broad for a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Please show source of `Power` function. `I tried better formatting` Please show your try. Sample code is greatly appreciated on stackoverflow.

Comment: Why do you need a function to compute 2^e where e is an integer?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for the advice. The array is fine, since the 360 node is 254's right child. The power function simply computes (in my case) 2 to the power of e, I tried adding the code to the comment but it was unreadable.
Also I tried better formatting with adding n/2 spaces (n = max number of leaves in the deepest node, wich is 2^height) before the first node and then adding n-1 for every new line.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write something along the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static int pow2i(int a) {
    int r = 1;
    while (a--) {
        r *= 2;
    }
    return r;
}

static void display_tree(const int *arr, size_t arrlen) {
    assert(arrlen);

    int longest_digits = 0;
    int tree_depth = 0;

    int pos = 0;
    int depth = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i <arrlen; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] != -1) {
            const int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", arr[i]);
            if (longest_digits < len) {
                longest_digits = len;
            }
        }
        
        if (pos == 0) {
            tree_depth++;
            pos = pow2i(depth++);
        }
        pos--;      
    }

    //printf("%d %d\n", longest_digits, tree_depth);

    pos = 0;
    depth = 0;
    const int additional_offset = 3;
    int max_width = pow2i(tree_depth) * (longest_digits + additional_offset);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrlen; ++i) {
        const bool first = pos == 0;
        if (first) {
            pos = pow2i(depth);
            depth++;
        }
        const int count_elems = pow2i(depth);
        const int chunk = max_width / count_elems;
        const int width = chunk + (first ? -chunk/2 : 0);
        const int pre_spaces = width - longest_digits;

        printf("%*s", pre_spaces, "");
        if (arr[i] == -1) {
            printf("%*s", longest_digits, "-");
        } else {
            printf("%*d", longest_digits, arr[i]);
        }

        if (pos == 1) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        pos--;
    }

}

int main() {
    assert(pow2i(0) == 1);
    assert(pow2i(1) == 2);
    assert(pow2i(3) == 2*2*2);
    int arr1[] = {15, 5, 19, 1, 14, -1, 254, -1, 3, 13, -1, -1, -1, 240, 360};
    display_tree(arr1, sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(*arr1));
}
```

The code outputs:

```
                      15
           5                      19
     1          14           -         254
  -     3    13     -     -     -   240   360
```

I reused your indexing, but renamed the single letter unknown variable `e` to `depth` something more meaningfull. First I calculate the longest count of digits in base-10 of all the numbers in the tree and find the maximum tree depth. Knowing that, I can calculate what would be the width of the tree at each depth and calculate increments in each depth:

```
            xxx            - depth = 1
        xxx       xxx      - depth = 2
      xxx  xxx  xxx  xxx   - depth = 3

    |-------------------| - width of the whole tree
    |---------|           - offset to first number
     ----|---------|----  - positions at depth=2
    |----|----|----|----| - chunks sizes at depth=3
```

From that you may calculate the count of spaces needed to insert between each positions.